# How to check whether or not the file's path is the filesystem in Android 7?

Tags: android, filesystems

Is there any code to check whether or not the file's path is the filesytems ("/storage" or "/storage/emulated/0" or "/") in Android 7 ? Because when I call below code, it returns null in case the path of "folder" relates to filesystems in Android 7. I want to check to show some message like "This is the File System of Android" before calling below code.

```
File[] childFiles = folder.listFiles();
```

Comment: folder.exists() ?

Comment: the result always returns to true in case the path is "/storage". I want to do some another behaviors if it relate to system file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `folder.exists()`. Or `folder.canRead()`.

But in Android 7 its impossible to list the "/" directory. And some other directories as you have seen.

Check `childFiles` for null and return if so.

Bad times ;-).

Comment: the result of "folder.exists()" always returns to true in case the path is "/storage". I want to do some another behaviors if it relate to system file.

Comment: The result of what? Paths do  exists but you will not be able to make listings as you have seen.

Comment: Is there anyway to check before calling some code like "listFiles" ? I want to show message about this file is the file system, can't access to it

Comment: Maybe folder.canRead() ? Please try.

Comment: But when the normal file doesn't have the "read permission" the "canRead" method returns to false ? I can't show the message "It is the fileSystem" in this case.

Comment: Please try folder.canRead() and report. Dont come with other questions before this is solved.

Comment: sorry let me try the method canRead :( I'm newbie

Comment: The canRead returns false, however it doesn't ensure the file is the filesystem like I ask like my question's title. Is there any way ?

Comment: If folder.exists() returns true then it is a file system path. What do you ask more? If a following canRead() returns false you cannot access it. Thats all i would think. Otherwise clarify what you want. Suddenly, and in the subject,  you talk about a file where your post is about directories. Confusing.